# Can't seem to get my UIButton to hide or change coordinates

Tags: iphone, xcode, button

The basic premise of my app is that when it loads it hides the button "findMe" and then when the button "go" is selected it shows the button and sets it to a specific coordinate (Once I fix this issue I am going to implement random coordinates). The problem is my button does not hide when the app loads and the "go" button does not change the coordinates. I created the button in interface builder. I am not sure why this is not working as this seems like such an easy task. Any help at where I went wrong is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Senior_DesignViewController : UIViewController 
<UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIButton *findMe;
    IBOutlet UIButton *go;
    IBOutlet UILabel *success;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *findMe;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *success;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *go;

-(IBAction)foundMe:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "Senior_DesignViewController.h"

@implementation Senior_DesignViewController

@synthesize findMe;
@synthesize success;
@synthesize go;

-(IBAction)foundMe:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alertDialog;
    alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                   initWithTitle:@"Congratulations" 
                   message:@"You have found the box" 
                   delegate:nil 
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertDialog show];
    [alertDialog release];
}

-(IBAction)go:(id)sender {

    findMe.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50);
    findMe.hidden = NO; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    findMe.hidden = YES;

    UIAlertView *alertDialog;
    alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle:@"Welcome to our SNR DSN App" 
                    message:@"Please Calibrate NOW!" 
                    delegate:nil 
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertDialog show];
    [alertDialog release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: have you attached the IBOutlet memebers to the buttons in IB?

Comment: Damn that worked. It was so simple and I feel stupid. Should have double checked that mistake. Had the IBActions taken care of. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Don't feel stupid until it happens a *second* time `:)`

Comment: Haha, that is what I don't want to happen. My senior project is to create an iPhone app for the FDA and I'm learning Obj-C coding all from scratch so I figured there will be silly road bumps like this along the way. Thanks again guys.

Comment: Don't take it hard, I still forget to hook 'em up sometimes. ;)

Comment: my favourite mistake is to setup the outlets, and hook them up in IB, then do a build and run without saving the IB document.

Comment: I know the question was answered in the comments, but this is still showing up as unanswered since there is not an accepted answer--hence my seemingly superfluous post.

Comment: During development I usually assert that my outlets are non-nil. This way if I forget (which I do occasionally), it'll at least slap me in the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the outlets and actions are hooked up in Interface Builder.  The buttons should be attached to the file owner as Referencing Outlets, and the actions should be hooked up to the Touch Up Inside event.